# jquery mobile 1.4, button with data-inline="true" is still full width

Tags: jquery-mobile

I just upgraded to JQM 1.4.2.

I have a button with `data-inline="true"` and it is still full container width.

Can you help please ?

My html :

```
<div id="blink">Enter your <span> "your Factor"</span>
  <a href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-icon-info ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-notext" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-position-to="origin">Learn more</a>:
</div>
```

Html enhanced by jqm :

```
<div id="blink">Enter your <span> "your Factor"</span>  
<a href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-icon-info ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-notext" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-position-to="origin" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="popupInfo" aria-expanded="false">Learn more</a>:
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add class `ui-btn-inline`.

Comment: well played @Omar !! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Omar for the solution.

We need to add the class `ui-btn-inline` to the html :

```
<div id="blink">Enter your <span> "your Factor"</span>
  <a href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-icon-info ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-position-to="origin">Learn more</a>:
</div>
```

JQM guys, can you please add this to your upgrade guide ?

Comment: remove `data-inline="true"` you dont need it. `.ui-btn-inline` replaces it.